# Suppose I have this javascript function. How do I pass the element to it?

Tags: javascript

```
function getLeftPos(elm){
  var left = 0;
  while(elm){
    left += elm.offsetLeft;
    elm= elm.offsetParent;
  }
  return left;
}
```

How come this doesn't work?

```
getLeftPos(document.getElementById("#frame"));
```

If I alert(elm) inside that function, it is NULL.

Comment: And what do you see if you alert(document.getElementById("#frame")); ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't put the # in the id.

```
getLeftPos(document.getElementById("frame"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Another viable answer to your question "how come this doesn't work" is:

Javascript != JQuery

Not trying to be snarky but its a really important thing to remember.

For core Javascript documentation a good resource in general is developer.mozilla.org and for [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById) in particular

Comment: ... yet learning to call dom els and perform pretty css tricks clearly goes far in toning javascript skills.